# Cordova, q.js thorwing e, android tools are in path

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ant

So I've looked at other answers for similar questions and everyone seems to say that to fix this issue I need to make sure that android-tools, tools, and ant are in my path. I've made sure they are in my path and yet I am still experiencing this issue. To ensure that I am doing everything right I have followed the instructions exactly from this page: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

I'm using Mac OS X and below you can see the error message exactly.

```
BUILD FAILED
/Users/408366/Desktop/adt/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:653: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/408366/Desktop/adt/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:698: null returned: 1

Total time: 1 second

/Users/408366/Google Drive/Web Design/AHS App/Tests/todo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/408366/Google Drive/Web Design/AHS App/Tests/todo/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/408366/Google Drive/Web Design/AHS App/Tests/todo/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

I'm using these commands to put these things in my path:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/408366/Desktop/adt/sdk/tools/:/Users/408366/Desktop/adt/sdk/platform-tools/:/Users/408366/Desktop/ant/bin
launchctl setenv PATH $PATH
```

Thank you!

Comment: I've been having this same error for a couple days now. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Check the file \hybrid\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js
At line 1718, there is a 'ms' variable. Instead, use an integer value like 15000.
The lines should look like:

```
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
            deferred.reject(new Error(message || "Timed out after " + ms + " ms"));
        }, 15000);
```

Enjoy!